# How do you handle the principal in microservice and REST API?

Tags: java, rest, microservices

Assume you are building a commenting system where authenticated users have to post comments. Authentication protocol is Oauth2.

You have an API  `POST /comment` And you pass the comment in the body of the request.

My question: because the users are authenticated, the identity of the user who creates the comment will be know to the API implementation. Do you also include the user's id in the body of the request? Or do you just use the principal provided by oauth protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the identity of the authenticated user, in this case, the principal. Because if you add the user id also in the body, anyone could change it using for example the browser debugging tools and comment like he was another user.

If you are using OAuth 2.0 there are two options, if you use an opaque token you should call the user info endpoint of your OAuth server to get the user details of a given token. If you are using a jwt token instead, the user id should be in the sub claim. Whatever the option you choose, you should use the user identity provided by your authentication mechanism